# Preact-compat returning component <undefined></undefined>

Tags: reactjs, components, react-dom, preact

I'm trying to use a React component (react-slider) and I'm getting `<undefined></undefined>`

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    import Slider from 'react-slider';
    const Range = Slider.Range;

    export class PreactTest{
      constructor(){ super(); }
      create(){
        render(
          <Range allowCross={false} defaultValue={[0, 20]} onChange={(x) => {console.log(x);} } />, "some-id")
        }
      }
     }
```

.babelrc

```
    {
  "sourceMaps": true,
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"],
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-decorators-legacy"],
    ["transform-react-jsx"],
    ["transform-class-properties"],
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": ["."],
        "alias": {
          "react": "preact-compat",
          "react-dom": "preact-compat"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Too bad no error is thrown or displayed in the console.  I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct Component react/preact syntax, please review this https://github.com/developit/preact#components

Your code should look more like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Range} from 'react-slider'

export default class PreactTest extends Component {
  render() {
    return (<Range allowCross={false} defaultValue={[0, 20]} onChange={(x) => {console.log(x);} } />)
  }
}
```

Then into another file do the `react-dom` rendering

```
import {render} from 'react-dom'
import PreactTest from './preact-test'

render(<PreactTest />, document.getElementById('some-id'))
```